# Gemfile: Difference Between branch and ref in a github Reference

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemfile

In the *Gemfile* it's possible to refer a gem hosted on github:

```
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '2-3-stable'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', ref: '2-1-stable'
```

The [Gemfile manpage](http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html) describes three attributes for git: *branch*, *ref* and *tag*. What's the difference between `ref` and `branch`? And how does bundler handle the gems differently depending on the attribute?

This especially seems to be interesting because you can only use one of the attributes at a time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `branch`, you're just specifying the git branch to pull from.  If you did a `bundle up <gem>` when targeting a branch, it would update to the tip of that branch.

The `ref` is really nailing it down to an individual commit.  You wouldn't give a "human-readable" name as you did in your question, you'd do something like:

```
gem 'something', github: 'someone/something', ref: '832e76a9'
```

And now you've pinned it to that ref.  If you did a `bundle up something`, it wouldn't change that gem (it may update its dependencies though).

Comment: Thank you. The human-readable _ref_ from above actually is working. So it is at least possible to reference a branch by using _ref_.